# How to change the index of an object inside of a collection

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry, collections

I'm using Geometry nodes to create a voxel like terrain, I have different model for each terrain type (grass, rock...) inside a collection. I also have a setup so that I can change between them through weight painting, which is linked to the instance index of a instance on points. But the order is not customizable it sets it up as dirt, grass, rock, but I want the order to be grass, dirt, rock. I've searched and I couldn't find an answer for this. Is there a way to change the order?[image: View of the viewport]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The objects in a collection are read in order.

The first object in a collection has index $0$, the second object has index $1$, and so on.

So the question is: *How can I change the order of objects within a collection?*.

The answer is:

**Start the identifier of an object with a number.**

For example, change the names of:

- Dirt
- Grass
- Rock

to:

- 000_Grass
- 001_Dirt
- 002_Rock

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at first it didn't work when I tried it, but it turns out you have to reparent it to the collection for it to change. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SebastianEspinoza You're welcome! By the way, it should also work if you simply deactivate and reactivate the Geometry Nodes modifier after a change. ...possibly a bug?